# While loop not checking correctly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop

Currently I have a while statement that loops through all cells below that are of a lower padding level and is supposed to remove said cells. Currently the below statement goes through about 3 of them then stops even though further cells meet the conditions.

```
if isExpanded[indexPath.item] //if already expanded remove
{
    var t = 1

    while (comment.paddingLevel != commentsData[indexPath.row + t].paddingLevel)
    {
        isExpanded.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row + t)

        preRenderedText.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row + t)
        commentsData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row + t)

        var path = NSIndexPath(forItem: indexPath.row + t, inSection: 0)
        t++
        delpaths.append(path)        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mutating the `isExpanded` array by deleting items from it - this means that the index for the next item is going to reduce by one, but you increment t regardless.  An `NSMutableIndexSet` is probably a better data structure to use for `isExpanded` rather than an array.

Comment: @Paulw11 Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the `isExpanded` array by deleting items from it - this means that the index for the next item is going to reduce by one, but you increment t regardless. An `NSMutableIndexSet` is probably a better data structure to use for `isExpanded` rather than an array.

An `NSMutableIndexSet` stores a set of integer indices - In this case it would be your `item` values.  Then you can use the set's `contains(item)` method to quickly get an answer as to whether a particular index is in the set or not.

Comment: Currently my array is a bool array how can I adapt NSMutableIndexSet to fit the same purpose?